# For Loop and Countif Function R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a for loop to count if the values in each row are larger than a cutoff value that changes from row to row in another matrix. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
for (i in 100) {
    
    count_Q4_l2 = NULL #set to zero after every loop
    
    for (j in 10000){
        if (ACT_Allquant2[1,i]>cc[j,1]){     #if the value in this column larger than the other, then count
            count_Q4_l2 <- count_Q4_l2+1     #+1 to count the values

        }
             }
    countALL[1,i] <- count_Q4_l2           #save the values into another data.frame
    
        }
    }
```

The cutoff values are in the ACT_Allquant2 table and they should move forward together with the for loop.
Hope I explained myself clearly and I thank you very much in advance for your help!!

EDIT:
ACT_Allquant2 looks the following way:

```
X91.      X92.      X93.     X94.     X95.     X96.     X97.     X98.
Qfourfac_netlg2  0.7685364 0.8995720 0.9896079 1.014982 1.066362 1.229381 
                     X99.    X100.
Qfourfac_netlg2  1.727864 2.318737
```

While cc is a series of column

```
      X1.       X2.       X3.       X4.       X5.       X6.       X7.       X8.       X9.
2 -2.504816 -2.433826 -2.305134 -2.261871 -2.110741 -1.894405 -1.344805 -1.256876 -1.211396
       X10.     X11.      X12.      X13.      X14.       X15.       X16.       X17.
2 -1.199943 -1.13323 -1.031908 -1.019844 -1.007079 -0.9932806 -0.9232708 -0.8316696
        X18.       X19.       X20.       X21.       X22.       X23.      X24.       X25.
2 -0.8052391 -0.7738284 -0.7334976 -0.7126213 -0.6950152 -0.6272749 -0.584775 -0.5540359
        X26.       X27.       X28.       X29.       X30.       X31.      X32.       X33.
2 -0.5307423 -0.5105184 -0.4107709 -0.4001571 -0.3959766 -0.3607601 -0.329242 -0.2746449
        X34.       X35.       X36.       X37.       X38.       X39.       X40.      X41.
2 -0.2231775 -0.1799284 -0.1684765 -0.1568755 -0.1446923 -0.1403811 -0.1387818 -0.126637
        X42.        X43.      X44.        X45.        X46.       X47.       X48.      X49.
2 -0.1082471 -0.08882241 -0.053299 -0.04695731 0.002623936 0.05961787 0.07482258 0.0868524
        X50.      X51.      X52.      X53.      X54.      X55.      X56.      X57.      X58.
2 0.09455113 0.1003998 0.1077676 0.1574778 0.1810591 0.1832488 0.1874931 0.1893803 0.1955026
       X59.      X60.      X61.      X62.      X63.      X64.      X65.      X66.     X67.
2 0.2035948 0.2321749 0.2453042 0.2604033 0.2739561 0.3018942 0.3835822 0.5748584 0.603411
       X68.      X69.      X70.      X71.      X72.      X73.      X74.     X75.     X76.
2 0.6580565 0.6882143 0.7104922 0.7568134 0.7769822 0.7932305 0.8550466 0.876781 1.084851
      X77.     X78.     X79.     X80.     X81.     X82.     X83.     X84.     X85.     X86.
2 1.117067 1.196249 1.261902 1.310987 1.423575 1.485869 1.606687 1.678782 1.950923 1.995428
     X87.    X88.     X89.     X90.    X91.     X92.     X93.     X94.    X95.     X96.
2 1.99818 2.04422 2.080644 2.205811 2.21738 2.356354 2.469436 2.484198 2.52253 2.564173
      X97.     X98.     X99.
2 2.638286 2.675248 2.768761
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I assume you want the loops from 1 to 100 and 1 to 10000, then you have change your syntax to `i in seq_len(100)` and `j in seq_len(10000)`

Comment: hello, I added some edits. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but let's try a simple example:

```
set.seed(41)
ACT <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 25, 4))
cc <- rnorm(4, 0, .5)
cc
# [1]  0.03641331  0.59785494 -1.05581599  0.33569523
```

In each column of ACT you want to count the values that exceed the value in cc, e.g. for column 1 the number that exceed 0.03641331, for column 2 the number that exceed 0.59785494? If that is so, you do not need any loops:

```
Comp <- sweep(ACT, 2, cc, ">")
Count <- colSums(Comp)
Count
# X1 X2 X3 X4 
# 16  8 22 10
```

You can extract the values that exceed the `cc` value for each column, but you cannot put them into a data frame since the number of values in each column is different. You can create a data frame with the coordinates of the larger values or a list with the values for each column:

```
Larger <- data.frame(which(Comp, arr.ind=TRUE), ACT[Comp])
head(Larger)
#   row col ACT.Comp.
# 1   2   1 0.1972575
# 2   3   1 1.0017043
# 3   4   1 1.2888254
# 4   5   1 0.9057534
# 5   6   1 0.4936675
# 6   7   1 0.5992858
LargerByCol <- split(Larger$ACT.Comp, Larger$col)
LargerByCol[[1]]
#  [1] 0.1972575 1.0017043 1.2888254 0.9057534 0.4936675 0.5992858 . . . 16 values
```